# How can you throw a checked exception without violating SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

There is a SonarQube rule that states that "[...no method throws a new checked exception.](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1162)"

And it gives the following code example:

```
public void myMethod1() throws CheckedException {
  ...
  throw new CheckedException(message);   // Noncompliant
  ...
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(message); // Compliant; IllegalArgumentException is unchecked
}

public void myMethod2() throws CheckedException {  // Compliant; propagation allowed
  myMethod1();
}
```

How then can you actually throw a custom checked exception?

Let's say I catch a IOException and do a getMessage() to get the detail message string of the IOException.

Then have a condition checks the content of the string to throw a more specific custom checked exception (extends Exception).

How do I actually accomplish this without violating SonarQubes rule that I not  `throw new CheckedException(message);` ?

Does this rule mean that SonarQube never wants the developer to throw a new custom checked exception?

Comment: Maybe, just maybe: could you do `throw new CheckedException(cause, message)`? Maybe sonarqube figured that you catch an exception and throw it away (and btw: passing on a "cause" is really good practice ... throwing them away: not so much).

Comment: the rule says you shouldn't throw checked exceptions. at all. it just allows you to propagate ones thrown elsewhere.

Comment: @GhostCat Nope. That still causes the SonarQube violation. I guess this rule just doesn't want you to throw ANY new checked exceptions.

Comment: What I don't understand is that with rule turned on, how one can throw a custom checked exception? For example you catch a generic exception, read the exception details, and then throw a more detailed custom checked exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the rule

> The purpose of checked exceptions is to ensure that errors will be
>   dealt with, either by propagating them or by handling them, **but some
>   believe** that checked exceptions negatively impact the readability of
>   source code, by spreading this error handling/propagation logic
>   everywhere.
>
> This rule verifies that no method throws a new checked exception.

It's not an absolute rule.
It's just up to you if you want to prevent people from throwing checked exceptions in your code.
Remember that Sonar rules are just rules, if you don't agree with some, simply disable them.
This one in particular looks very opinion-based.

If you can't disable it, resolve the issue as `won't fix` and add a comment to explain that you need to throw this exception because the architecture requires so.

Personally I think that checked exception are a bit annoying but I wouldn't enable this rule, I don't find it relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but I don't own that code base, thus can't change the SonarQube rules. Simply trying to fix a ton of SonarQube errors and refactor spaghetti code.

Comment: The rule is simple, `don't throw checked exception`. If you still want to throw a checked exception, disable the rule or resolve the issue as `won't fix`